# C - How to pass struct pointer array to a function by reference

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[31];
    int played;
    int won;
    int lost;
    int tie;
    int points;
} Player;
```

And this function which fill the struct array with data from file:

```
int load(Player *players[], int max_players, int *player_count)
{
    static const char filename[] = "players.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[128]; 

        players = malloc(max_players * sizeof *players);

        while (1) /* read until end of file */
        {

            players[*player_count] = malloc(sizeof(Player));

            if (*player_count < max_players && fgets(players[*player_count]->name, sizeof players[*player_count]->name, file) != NULL)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count]->played);    // read played
                fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count]->won);       // read won 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count]->lost);      // read lost 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count]->tie);       // read tie 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count]->points);    // read points 
                fgets(line, sizeof line, file);                         // read new line

                // increase player count
                *player_count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now I am having a problem with calling it by passing players as a reference so that the updated data of players gets reflected at the calling end.

Below is my calling code, which I think has the problem:

```
Player *players[MAX_PLAYERS] = { NULL };
int playerCount = 0;
load(players, MAX_PLAYERS, &playerCount);
```

When I debug the code, the players' array gets filled in the function but when it returns back, the players' value is still null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `load` should be able to modify the contents of the array. Show at least some of your `load` code. I suspect a problem there.

Comment: updated load(). Please check.

Comment: when the call to `fopen()` fails, the code should call `perror( "your error message" )` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.

Comment: remove the calls to `fgets()` else extract the data from the array `line[]` via `sscanf()` not `fscanf()`.  In the posted code, two lines from the file are skipped for each line of data that is processed

Comment: the 'typical' return value is 0 for success, 1 ( or -1 ) for failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the local variable `players`.

Remove the below line from the function you don't need it.

```
   players = malloc(max_players * sizeof *players);|
```

As you already have the array of pointers in `main`.

---

You don't need array of pointers of type `Player` you just need array of type `Player`

```
Player *players;
load(&players, MAX_PLAYERS, &playerCount);
```

And in `load` function.

```
int load(Player **players, int max_players, int *player_count)
{
    static const char filename[] = "players.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[128]; 

        (*players) = malloc(max_players * sizeof **players);

        while (1) /* read until end of file */
        {


            if (*player_count < max_players && fgets((*players)[*player_count].name, sizeof (*players)[*player_count].name, file) != NULL)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d", &(*players)[*player_count].played);    // read played
                fscanf(file, "%d", &(*players)[*player_count].won);       // read won 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &(*players)[*player_count].lost);      // read lost 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &(*players)[*player_count].tie);       // read tie 
                fscanf(file, "%d", &(*players)[*player_count].points);    // read points 
                fgets(line, sizeof line, file);                         // read new line

                // increase player count
                *player_count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf()` will read from the file, however, the call to `fgets()` will have already consumed the line in the file and placed its' contents into `line[]`  so those contents will be 'skipped'.. The results is two lines of input will be skipped for every line processed.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support passing a variable by reference.

I just kept it simple. Your function should look like this:

```
int load(Player *players, int max_players, int *player_count)
{
    static const char filename[] = "players.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[128]; 

        while (!feof(file ) && !ferror(file )) /* read until end of file */
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count].played);    // read played
            fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count].won);       // read won 
            fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count].lost);      // read lost 
            fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count].tie);       // read tie 
            fscanf(file, "%d", &players[*player_count].points);    // read points 
            fgets(line, sizeof line, file);                         // read new line

            // increase player count
            *player_count += 1;
        }

        fclose(file);

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and main:

```
int main ()
{
    Player players[MAX_PLAYERS] = { NULL };
    int playerCount = 0;
    load(players, MAX_PLAYERS, &playerCount);
    printf("");
}
```

Comment: @kiranBiradar thanks. corrected as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/1911652)

Comment: @kiranBiradar, next time it would be nice to give a link to *why* it's wrong :)

Comment: Sorry I was typing through mobile and  couldn't embed link.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. has not been compiled as the OP did not post a minimal, complete, verifiable example
2. properly passes the parameters
3. properly checks for errors
4. performs the desired functionality
5. shows how to initialize the pointer in `main()`
6. shows how to update the pointer in `main()`
7. follows the plan that unrecoverable errors cause the code to output to `stderr` all the error information, then exits
8. follows the 'typical' returned value of '0' for success
9. be sure, in `main()` to pass all the allocated memory pointers to `free()` to avoid a memory leak

and now, the proposed code modifications:

```
regarding:

    typedef struct 
    {
        char name[31];
        int played;
        int won;
        int lost;
        int tie;
        int points;
    } Player;

this anonymous struct will be very difficult to display 
the individual fields via a debugger,
because debuggers use the 'tag' name of the struct 
to reference the individual fields


in main function: Notice only declaring a pointer initialized to NULL,
then passing the address of the pointer to the function: `load()`

    Player *players =  NULL;
    int playerCount = 0;
    load(&players, &playerCount);  

notice the double '**' on the 'players' parameter
This enables the sub function to modify the pointer field in the caller

    int load(Player **players, int *player_count)
    {
        static const char filename[] = "players.txt";

        // it is poor programming practice to name a variable the
        // same as a struct, so changed `file` to `fp`
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if( !fp )
        {
            perror( "fopen to read players.txt failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fopen successful

        // increased the size of the input buffer `line[]` for safety
        char line[1024]; 

        // note: used `calloc()` so when cleaning up from error
        //       no need to check if a specific entry in the 'player'
        //       array is used.  `free()` handles a NULL parameter just fine
        *players = calloc( MAX_PLAYERS, sizeof(Player*) );
        if( !*players )
        {
            perror( "calloc for array of pointers to players failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        /* read until end of file  or array full*/
        while (*player_count < MAX_PLAYERS && fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) 
        {
            (*players)[*player_count] = malloc(sizeof(Player));
            if( !(*players)[ *player_count ] )
            {
                perror( "malloc for individual player failed" );
                for( int i=0; i<MAX_PLAYERS; i++ )
                {
                    free( (*players)[i] );
                }
                free( *players ); 
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, malloc successful

            if( sscanf( line, "%d %d %d %d %d", 
                players[*player_count]->played,    // read played
                players[*player_count]->won,       // read won 
                players[*player_count]->lost,      // read lost 
                players[*player_count]->tie,       // read tie 
                players[*player_count]->points) != 5 )   // read points 
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "extraction of player fields failed\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }


            // increase player count
            (*player_count) += 1;
        }

        fclose(file);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## I THINK YOUR FUNCTION SHOULD BE WRITED LIKE THIS

```
int func(int ***players){
    *players=new int* [MAXSIZE];
    //use this if use c
    // *players=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*MAXSIZE);
    for(int i=0;i<MAXSIZE;i++){
        *(*players+i)=new int[2];
        // *(*players+i)=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2); 
        //2 is test can choose every number if your computer allow
    }
}
```

and you main should like this main:

```
int main(){

    int **players=nullptr;
    func(&players);
    //use follow if you must delete 
    for(int i=0;i<MAXSIZE;i++){
        delete players[i];
    }
    delete players;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {    int played;} Player;


void load(Player* &players, int max_players, int &player_count)
{
    players = (Player*)malloc(max_players * sizeof(Player));

    for (int i = 0; i < max_players; i++)
    {
        players[i].played = i;
        player_count++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_PLAYERS=3;
    Player* players=  NULL ;
    int playerCount = NULL;
    load(players, MAX_PLAYERS, playerCount);

    //...
    free(players);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- struct:

```c
typedef struct Foo {
  int x;
} Foo;
```

function:

```c
void f(Foo **foo) {
  foo[0]->x = 2021;                // already allocate in main
  foo[1]    = malloc(sizeof(Foo)); // not locate yet
  foo[1]->x = 2022;
}
```

- main:

```c
int main() {
  Foo **foo = malloc(100 * sizeof(Foo *)); // foo[10]

  foo[0]    = malloc(sizeof(Foo));         // must allocate before using
  foo[0]->x = 2020;                        // assing 2021 to foo[0].x must use arrow for pointer

  f(foo);
  foo[1]->x = 2024;                        // already allocate in function f();

  printf("main: value of x: %d\n", foo[0]->x);
  printf("main: value of x: %d\n", foo[1]->x);
}
```

- Output:

```sh
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
value of x: 2021
value of x: 2024
```